# Stylish for Android?

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

I've occasionally used [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/%20Stylish) to improve usability of websites on the PC. Is there an equivalent for Android - either plugin to FireFox, the default browser (mine is a Galaxy Note), or other. Basically, there are some sites that don't have mobile-specific stylesheets that I'd love to improve with a bit of CSS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stylish 1.3b1](http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/32052/stylish-for-firefox-1.3b1) adds support for Firefox Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mobyware there's a [Stylish-Custom Addon available](http://www.mobyware.net/google-android-2-2-1-device-1909/stylish-custom-firefox-addon-download-free-25583.html) for the mobile Firefox. The page also mentions you need the Stylish Addon itself to make it work -- however, I could not find that. The compatibility list starts with Android 2.0 and goes up through the version to 4.0 (ICS), a list of compatible devices is available as well.

Moreover, some [discussions on userstyles.org](http://forum.userstyles.org/search?Search=android) seem to mention some availability for Android, you might want to check them out.

Not sure if it works, I didn't try myself as I do not use the mobile Firefox -- but you might give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It gets a rating of 1.5 stars out of 5 - wonder what it did to deserve that?

Comment: No idea. As I wrote, I do not use the mobile FF - but I make extensive use of Stylish on my desktop. I just thought the little information I found could prove more useful to you than no answer at all -- especially as there was none for months...

Answer (score 1):

There is [Stylish add-on](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.pmmlabs.stylish) for the Dolphin Browser.